# Can't send mail in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the following code for sending mail in codeigniter

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_mailtype('html');
$this->email->from('test@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('test2@example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Here I'm getting the error as

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

But if the mail type is change to text, ie

```
$this->email->set_mailtype('text');
```

It works fine.Why is it so ?

Comment: This seems like a problem with your email client rather than Codeigniter. What client are you using? What's your stack?

Comment: Did you configure the email library ?

Comment: See this. Could be the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859958/codeigniter-unable-to-send-email-using-php-mail

Comment: @ChrisTill that worked.I was not having email.php file. Thanks

Comment: Awesome :) Glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Need an email.php file.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```

reference, this URL: http://www.ciboard.co.kr/user_guide/en/libraries/email.html

Comment: codeIgniter, system/libralies/Email.php, need a setting.