# Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Tags: php, codeigniter

i tried to send the mail using codeigniter framework.but it will raise the error "Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

```
From: "prakash t" <tprakashkce@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <tprakashkce@gmail.com>
Reply-To: "tprakashkce@gmail.com" <tprakashkce@gmail.com>
X-Sender: tprakashkce@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5aed4eed40506@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?UTF-8?Q?Test=20Mail?=
hai this my test mail
```

"
but no use

here is mycode:

public function sendMail(){

```
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'mail',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'example@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*********'
    );
```

I know it's duplicate question.but i didn't find solution for my question

```
    $this->load->library('email',$config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('tprakashkce@gmail.com','prakash t');
    $this->email->to('tprakash11121996@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Test Mail');
    $this->email->message('hai this my test mail');

    if($this->email->send()){
        echo "mail send succesfully";
    }
    else{
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter unable to send email using PHP mail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859958/codeigniter-unable-to-send-email-using-php-mail)

Comment: `'smtp_port' => 587`, should be `smtp_port' => 465,`

Comment: i tried 587 and 465. but no use

Comment: @PrakashT Don't forget to accept answers that helped you https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Bro just accept my answer if your issue is solved with that !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are done all correct but you have issue on initialize the mail

Just change this

`$this->load->library('email',$config);`

to

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

You can check [in details here.](https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-send-email-gmail-smtp-server/)

Comment: You are most welcome :) and now just close your question by accepting my answer by click the right button beside my answer

Comment: okay but you can just click the tick symbol near my answer so that my answer will be got accepted by you.

Comment: Bro i ask another question related this post pls help me  bro https://stackoverflow.com/q/50187796/9658774

Answer (score 0):

I got same error but my problem was with Apache configuration. Ensure that Apache can send emails.

To check your current sendmail status:
`sestatus -b | grep httpd_can_sendmail`

Change it to this if it is off: 
`sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on`